# ¿Cómo poner el cursor en modo espera en visual basic.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, webforms

Ya tengo la referencia "System.Windows.Forms" agregada a mi proyecto y lo estoy implementando como pueden ver aquí:

```
Protected Sub btnTerminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTerminar.Click

    'AQUÍ LE DIGO QUE ESTA EN ESPERA
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

    'AQUÍ HAY UN MÉTODO QUE SE ESTARÁ EJECUTANDO, ADEMÁS TIENE OTRA FUNCIÓN PARA ENVIAR UN CORREO EN DONDE TAMBIÉN LE HE PUESTO EL CURSOR EN MODO WAIT Y DEFAULT, PERO NO HAY RESULTADO. 
    Corregir(False)
    lblMinuto.Text = Convert.ToString(Duracion - 1)
    lblSegundo.Text = "59"

    'AQUÍ LE DIGO QUE VUELVE A LA NORMALIDAD
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default

End Sub
```

**Vista 'SimuladorExamen.aspx'**

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="Simulacro.Master" CodeBehind="SimuladorExamen.aspx.vb" Inherits="waSimExamen.SimuladorExamen" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <link href="css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jscript/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jscript/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jscript/themes/blitzer/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="jscript/cursor.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--ESTE SERIA EL CODIGO DEL CURSOR-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Message(msg) {
            $("#msg").html(msg);

            $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Aceptar: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<%--    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="185000"></asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" Interval="185000"></asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">               
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTerminar" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>

            <!-- MESSAGE BOX -->
            <div id="dialog-message" title="Simulacro de examen">
                <p id="msg"></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Fin  del Message Box -->

            <%--<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>--%>

            <table width="950">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="Red" height="35">SIMULACRO DE EXAMEN DE ADMISION</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div style="position: fixed; width: 950px;">
                            <table width="90%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td align="center" width="200" bgcolor="Red" height="30">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTiempo" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkVolver" runat="server" CssClass="BotonLink" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" Visible="False">Volver a empezar</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMinuto" runat="server" Text="2" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSegundo" runat="server" Text="59" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small">
                        <%-- <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="550" Width="92%" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Outset">--%>
                        <%--  <div style="overflow: auto; width: 92%; height: 550px">--%>
                        <asp:ListView ID="lvPreguntas" runat="server">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <table width="90%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="15%"></td>
                                        <td width="15%"></td>
                                        <td width="40%"></td>
                                        <td width="30%"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>

                                </table>
                            </LayoutTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" align="left" style="font-weight: bold" height="50" valign="bottom"><%#Eval("Tema")%></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight: bold" valign="top"><%#Eval("Orden")%>.-</td>
                                    <td colspan="3" align="left" style="text-align: justify"><%#Eval("Pregunta")%></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgA" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" Visible="False" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">A.</td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdResp1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Opcion1")%>' GroupName="Respuesta" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td rowspan="4">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgFigura" runat="server" Height="150" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgB" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" Visible="False" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">B.<asp:Label ID="lblFigura" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Imagen")%>' Visible="False"></asp:Label></td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdResp2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Opcion2")%>' GroupName="Respuesta" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgC" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" Visible="False" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">C.<asp:Label ID="lblRespuesta" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Respuesta")%>' Visible="False"></asp:Label></td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdResp3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Opcion3")%>' GroupName="Respuesta" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgD" runat="server" Height="20" Width="20" Visible="False" /></td>
                                    <td valign="top">D.</td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdResp4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Opcion4")%>' GroupName="Respuesta" /></td>
                                </tr>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                        <%--   </div>--%>
                        <%--  </asp:Panel>--%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table width="70%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" height="50" width="50%">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnTerminar" runat="server" Text="Finalizar" Width="120px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="25px" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" width="50%">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnVolver" runat="server" Text="Volver a empezar" Width="120px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" Height="25px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Es por eso que he puesto nuevamente esas 2 lineas de código para que haya resultados, pero tampoco sucede nada. Cuando hago debug, el código si se esta ejecutando. Espero que me puedan ayudar con esta pregunta, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es una app web, en las etiquetas que puse que estoy usando visual basic.net, pense que con eso se aclararía jeje, para la proxima seré más explicito.

Comment: No. Visual basic es el lenguaje de programacion. Winforms es para diseñar apps de escritorio. Vs2017 es la ide de desarrollo. Estan todas las etiquetas mal y por eso no tenes respuestas. Y por eso te pregunte si era de escritorio o web. Y por eso te pase una solucion para winforms. Y aunque sea vb, estas usando asp.net, pq esa es la tecnologia que usas para hacer las paginas. Y falta que aclares que modelo de vista usas. Puro? Razor? Algun otro? Te recomiendo que leas y entiendas en que estas trabajando. Y edites tu pregunta y aclares todo eso. No la proxima vez. Ahora. Usa el boton [edit]

Comment: Efectivamente, le debo una gran disculpa amigo "@gbianchi", yo si me estaba refiriendo a los webforms, pero me confundí con poner windows-form. De verdad una gran sincera disculpa.

Comment: ya esta amigo "@gbianchi"  :)

Comment: El *Namespace* `System.Windows.Forms` no es para `Windows Form`? creo que si

Comment: Así es, me encontré con esa librería de casualidad y la agregue a referencias para solucionar el problema del cursor, pero al parecer no se pudo.